# Sending POST (or GET) data to a PHP script using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, post, get

I'm trying to build a simple "I viewed this" function in a php directory for an intranet site.

So when a user has read the page, they click a button at the bottom that says "I've read this" that sends the users User ID and the page ID to a simple database table that I can then harvest for other uses.

I'm trying to do it with AJAX and PHP.

Here's my code:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function viewSave(form) {
var itemid = <?php echo $itemid; ?>;
var userid = <?php echo $userid; ?>;

var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

 xmlhttp.open("GET","saveView.php?q=itemid="+itemid+"&userid="+userid,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>
```

and I've set up a simple form with hidden fields:

```
<form onSubmit="return viewSave(this)" >
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

When I click submit, the URL changes and I get my variables, like this:

> thispage.php?itemid=455&userid=999&submit=Save

but "saveView.php" is not called and the data is not sent.

Here's what's in saveView.php:

```
<?php


$userid =$_GET["userid"];
$itemid = $_GET["itemid"];

  // Connect to the database
            $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'viewsave');

            // Write the data to the database
            $query = "INSERT INTO saves (entryID, userid, itemid) VALUES ( '0', '$userid', '$itemid')";
            mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
```

?>

I'm guessing the URL params are only appearing because of the form and that there's something wrong with the JavaScript.

I'm only a beginner with JS.

Help appreciated.

Ray.

Comment: Off-topic, but You could save yourself a lot of time and headaches over browser compatibility if you'd use jQuery

Comment: why are you embedding the values into your JS **AND** into the form? `...php?q="+itemid,userid` is also not doing what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your `php` file needs a name:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","save.php?
```

Then your parameters need names:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","save.php?q=itemid="+itemid+"&userid="+userid,true);
```

Then, in PHP you can use `$_GET` to get the data (and check it's a number):

```
if(array_key_exists('itemid', $_GET) && !is_nan($_GET['itemid'])) {
    $itemid = $_GET['itemid'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you Adam!

I tried your code but I'm still not getting the data through to the database...

I've made edits to the code above.